# can't view html5 canvas contents on localhost

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

i have the following code in an html file and when i try to view the code on localhost [MAMP] all i see is a black canvas area with a border around it. i've checked it in chrome and firefox. same results. what am i doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>      
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500" style="border:1px solid #000;"></canvas>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.pack.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            var myCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            ctx.fillRect(50, 50, 100, 100);
        //close jquery  
        });         
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Seem to be correct as you are only painting a black square.. canvas is transparent by default and default fill style is black.

Comment: @Ken-AbdiasSoftware, how would you suggest removing the default transparency?

Comment: heyjohnmurray: you need to fill the canvas with a solid color (you can set a background color on the element but this won't be a part of the content that you work with through the context).

Comment: Scott's answer shows in detail what you need to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

so i figured it out. thanks to Ken and Scott for their help.

```
var myCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillRect(50, 50, 100, 100);
```

should have been

```
var myCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = myCanvas.getContext("2d"); //should have been myCanvas not canvas
ctx.fillRect(50, 50, 100, 100);
```

Comment: Didn't catch that one +1. But you shouldn't be able to draw *anything* in that case ;)

Answer (score 3):

The default fill style of the canvas is black, while the canvas itself starts out as transparent.  Set it to something else before calling fillRect, and you'll see better results.

```
ctx.fillStyle = "#F00"
```

Or, try this to see multiple rectangles:

```
var myCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "green";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, myCanvas.width, myCanvas.height);
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fillRect(50, 50, 100, 100);
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/CpQK4/)

Comment: Default fill style is black solid. You probably mean (as I stated in the comment) that canvas is transparent by default.

Comment: @Ken-AbdiasSoftware Fixed, hopefully you'll like this better.  :-)